# Interpreting SMS messages from GSM modem

Tags: sms, communication, gsm, modem, telecommunication

I would like to be able to output information from a quad band GSM modem. The modem would be connected to a computer, and the idea is that I could send AT commands or SMS from very large distances to the modem. The modem would receive the instructions and would reply in SMS to the sender with the proper information. I am a little overwhelmed in how to approach this however, does anyone have any experience or insight with this? In particular, I am pretty lost on how I would process the received instructions and have the computer execute them.

An example of what I'm trying to do:

- Send SMS reading "Power info" to modem
- Modem receives SMS, relays it to the computer
- Computer sees instruction, fetches necessary data
- Computer outputs data to the modem
- Modem sends SMS to sender with the proper data (in this case volts/amps being used or something)

Please let me know if anything is unclear, it is my first time posting here.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have ruled out making the remote computer connect to the internet via GPRS and send regular reports over that connection?

Comment: Not really, I am willing to do it through GPRS also, it's just that GSM seems to be more available globally.